# How to avoid duplicate entries in database access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, duplicates

I'm creating a Registration form

How can i Prevent a data from duplicating when i save a data to my Ms access Database , something like Error handling for duplicate data or same First Name/Last Name and a message box that says there's a duplicated data.

As for now this is the code that i saw someone uses.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If Fname.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString() Then
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Info")
            Return
        End If
    Next
```

Do you guys have any suggestion , Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question isn't really coherent. You ask about how avoid duplicate entries and then you show code that finds duplicate entries and then you provide an error message that has nothing to do with duplicate entries. You need to try again. This time, provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, including an explanation of exactly what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it and what happens when you try. Finding duplicate data in a `DataGridView` has nothing to do with avoiding duplicate entries when populating or querying a database. Be SPECIFIC.

Comment: Thank you for the advice , i revised my question hope it made it somewhat clear?

Comment: Still rather poor, I'm afraid. The fact that people can't explain their problems means that they don't understand their problems, which makes it unsurprising that they can't solve their problems. A FULL and CLEAR explanation means ALL of the relevant information. This is how I think you should be explaining this but I have to guess because you haven't provided all the relevant information:

Comment: *"I have populated a `DataGridView` with data from a database. The user is entering new records via `TextBoxes`. I want to make sure that the new data doesn;t already exist in the grid before adding it and then saving it to the database. How do I go about checking the grid to see whether it already contains the data in the boxes?"*. That's the sort of description you need to provide. If that is not complete accurate regarding the current problem then provide a description like that that is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for what you asked, but personally I would check if Data matches the one in DB instead of DataGridView, because Users can edit them if you don't set ReadOnly property to true.

```
Private Sub DuplicatePrevention(datagridview As DataGridView, name As String)
    Dim duplicateCount As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To datagridview.Rows.Count - 1
        If datagridview.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString = name Then
            duplicateCount += 1
        End If
    Next
    If duplicateCount = 0 Then
        'fire your Query
    Else
        MsgBox(name & " exist already", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```